# Opening existing project using xampp

Tags: yii2

I have a ready yii2 project but it was created another computer. Now I want to change the project using my localhost xampp. How can I open my yii2 project in order to change and can see using localhost xampp?

Answer (score 2):

Xampp will have a folder named - `htdocs`.
Copy the project in that folder.

For example, you have a project named - yii2-project, copy it inside htdocs
it will look like:- `xampp/htdocs/yii2-project`

Start your xampp server, and in the browser address bar - 
go - `localhost/project-folder-name`  for this example - `localhost/yii2-project`

Comment: And remeber to add a copy of your DB in your local phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

Just use an Open Server.
Place a site folder in 'domains' and run Open Server